# How does ElasticSearch rank filter queries (rather than text queries)?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, ranking, tf-idf

I know that ElasticSearch uses [relevance ranking algorithms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) such as Lucene's [tf/idf, length normalization and couple of more algorithms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html) to rank term queries applied on textual fields (i.e. searching words "medical" AND "journal" in the "title" and "body" fields).

My question is how does ElasticSearch rank and retrieve results of a filter or range query (i.e. age=25, or weight>60)?

I know these types of queries are just filtering documents based on the condition(s). But lets say I have 200 documents which their age field value is 25. Which of those documents will be retrieved as top 10 results?

Does ElasticSearch retrieve them by the order it indexed them?

Comment: You have to know first that elasticsearch has two types of filters : 'query filters' and 'post filters'. The query filter will act like a boolean query. ex: age = 25 or not before scoring but the post filter will filter after the scoring is made but in both cases, you'll not get the filtered values!

Answer (score 4):

From the Elasticsearch documentation:

[Filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html): As a general rule, filters should be used instead of queries:

- for binary yes/no searches
- for queries on exact values

[Queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html): As a general rule, queries should be used instead of filters:

- for full text search
- where the result depends on a relevance score

So when running a search such as "age=25, or weight>60" you should be using a filter.

However - **Filters do not affect the scoring** - i.e. if you only used a filter your search results would all have the same score.

There is a [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) - this is a query that would affect score and I would guess that it scores documents based on things like the document timestamp (most recent gets a higher score).

You'd need to explore the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) further and dig into Lucene documentation to understand exactly how and why the a document got its score - but as above, you may be better using Filters that don't affect scoring.

Comment: I know that I should use filters and also filters have no ranking and scoring algorithms behind them. But they still need to and retrieve results in a sorted manner to be consistent. What that default sorting manner is? I have a suspicion that it is time stamp, but in my experience, it is not totally right. It seems that ElasticSearch retrieves them by time stamps in chunks meaning that it retrieves 20 of them by time stamps, then jumps to another document and retrieve more results by time stamps. I need some documentation that explains the behavior, not trial and error guess.

Comment: by default the sorting is done on score. So if you score all documents the same and don't apply any additional sorting the results are going to be fairly random.  When I test it out I consistently get the same document when using "size": 1, "from": 10. But when using  "size": 1, "from": 10000 then different results are returned - this looks to me like its pulling values from a cache rather than date ordering or anything else.

Comment: That is smart if they pull data from the cashe because they are have the same score and we therefor they are allowed to show any of them! They increase the speed by retrieving from the cache. But the downside is that it won't be consistent.
I am still looking for documentation available on ElasticSearch.org website.